# Automating PHP code generation for a database wrapper class?

Tags: php, mysql, automation, code-generation

I'm currently trying to create a couple of wrapper classes for a MySQL database. Basically, my goal is to eliminate the need to write any SQL at all and keep it all in PHP. I know that at scale this may not be a good solution, but it's good for simple setups like the one I'm working on now =)

I want to be able to hook this code up to any MySQL table and automatically generate functions that handle CRUD commands. For example, I have about 20 columns in a table called Users, and I want 4 functions for each column: Create, Read, Update, and Delete. I won't actually need ALL of them, but this is supposed to be just a layer that I then build my real PHP apps off of.

I am trying to automate these classes I'm making because it's extremely repetitive and it should be very simple to automate the generation.

To illustrate, where 'name' is a column in the Users table:

```
function createName($name) {

    if($stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . 
       '(name) values ("' . $name . '")')) {
           $stmt -> execute();
           $stmt -> fetch();
           $stmt -> close();
    }
    else {
        echo "error: " . mysqli_error($this->db);
    }
}
```

This could be generalized to:

```
function create{columnTitle}({$desiredValue}) {

    if($stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . 
                $this->table . '({columnTitle}) values ("' . {$desiredValue} . '")')) {
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> fetch();
        $stmt -> close();
    }
    else {
        echo "error: " . mysqli_error($this->db);
    }
}
```

Where {columnTitle} is the name of the column in question, and {desiredValue} is what you want the columns' value to be for that entry.

So literally every single CREATE function is going to be exactly the same, except the function name and parameter name will be equal to the name of the table column in question. I feel as though I should be able to get all the columns in a database and automatically change the variable and function names instead of creating 80 boilerplate functions (4 for each column) and then doing find/replace a million times.

Any ideas?

I'd like to make it work on any database tables so that I could put it on github for anyone to use. So basically the flow would go:

- grab all tables in a database
- for each table:

  - grab all columns in table

    - generate CREATE functions for all columns
    - generate READ functions for all columns
    - generate UPDATE functions for all columns
    - generate DELETE functions for all columns

Comment: Update: I figured out that a) I don't need to use this behavior and b) If I needed to, I can use PHP's __call() magic function to create this behavior.